# How do I read the effective cgroups limits for the current process using /sys/fs/cgroup

Tags: cgroups

I'm looking for the simplest recipe for reading the cgroups v1 and v2 effective values for CPU limits affecting my own process (using file system operations not OS commands).

From the kernel docs and looking around I *think* the main steps are something like this - but I really want to get it right to avoid it breaking on certain OSes/cgroups versions:

1. locate the cgroups root mount directory (typically /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct for v1 and /sys/fs/cgroup for v2, but could in theory be mounted somewhere else I believe?) --> probably grepping for cgroup in /proc/self/mountinfo is needed for this?
2. since the above is the root cgroup and my own process might be in a more specific child cgroup, I think I need locate the subdirectory of the /sys/fs/cgroup[/cpu,cpuacct] root corresponding to the cgroup my process is actually in? --> My best guess is to use "/proc/self/cgroup" to find out what this subdir is, though if I'm running inside a container it appears this path (e.g. /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker/xxxxxxxx) does not exist, so maybe I just fallback to the root cgroup? Is that a safe thing to do?
3. Once I've found the directory for my own process's cgroup, I need to read the limit files (e.g. cpu.max, if using cgroups2). I'm not quite clear on whether all the files (e.g. cpu.max) are always present in all cgroup directories, or only at parts of the hierarchy where a limit is added? Do I need to look at all directories starting with the deepest level cgroup and then working backwards until I find a cpu.max file that exists?
4. In case cgroups1 and cgroups2 are both running on the same system (seems to be allowed), do I prefer the cgroups2 files if present and fall back to cgroups1 if not, or the other way around?

I couldn't figure it out from the OS/kernel docs and was surprised I couldn't find a short blog or code snippet answering this question of how to get the /sys/fs directory containing the effective values for my own process... if there is one then great, if not perhaps this StackOverflow question is a good place for the information to live!

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into a problem with the cgroup v2 implementation for the OpenJDK and also found the documentation lacking. The [cgroup implementations for Java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/hotspot/os/linux) are the most comprehensive I've found, but I've still had to resort to testing with SystemD drop-ins created by `systemctl set-property` to try and untangle the behaviour.

For cgroup v1 and SystemD the effective limits are seemingly straight forward, because you just read `/proc/self/cgroup` and the hierarchy can be read directly from the file:

```
12:blkio:/
11:perf_event:/
10:cpuset:/
9:pids:/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-c3.scope
8:rdma:/
7:cpu,cpuacct:/user.slice
6:hugetlb:/
5:devices:/user.slice
4:net_cls,net_prio:/
3:memory:/user.slice
2:freezer:/
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-c3.scope
0::/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-c3.scope
```

However, this behaviour is SystemD specific, and only reflects the nearest configured node in the hierarchy. If an ancestor cgroup has a higher limit, that's something you need to walk the hierarchy to discover.

For cgroup 2 there's a single unified hierarchy:

```
0::/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-14.scope
```

Subtree control can now be delegated, leading to the controller files being present on all child cgroups, even when they don't have a limit configured, so they'll reflect the default. In fact `DefaultMemoryAccounting` was turned on by default in SystemD 238, so when you look at your current cgroup that doesn't have limits set, you'll see `max` for memory limits:

```
# Subtree Control

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-14.scope/cgroup.subtree_control

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-60004.slice/cgroup.subtree_control
memory pids

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/cgroup.subtree_control
memory pids

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
cpuset cpu io memory pids

# Memory Maximum

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-60004.slice/session-14.scope/memory.max
max

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-60004.slice/memory.max
max

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/memory.max
268435456
```

The implementations I've looked at also indicate there are cases where you can have a cgroup v1/v2 hybrid. In that case, any hierarchy > 0 in the cgroups file is controlled by cgroup v1 and my understanding is you can ignore those controllers for cgroup v2.

This would all be far simpler `.effective` file for each controller file, but as it stands, you need to detect whether cgroup v1 or v2 is in control, what kind of hierarchy is in use, and walk it to find the lowest limit.

Where you're only concerned about system level limits, which was our case because we use https://github.com/lxc/lxcfs on our container platform, then you can simplify and naively read the root of the cgroup fs.